# Software with post-scan abilities of Camscanner for windows?

Tags: windows, scanning, pdf-editor

I am looking for a software which mostly does what the android app Camscanner does after a photo is captured.

I have lot of scanned PDFs with greyish page color. I want to primarily convert them to black/white or greyish PDF. Which camnscanner excellently handles. But since its a subscription based service, it has limitations like no. of PDFs that can be imported etc.

The scanned documents have lot of math symbols and equations. Since no OCR engine is good recognizing these. I'm not inclined to OCR the PDFs.

So these are list of features I need:

1. Remove the greyish page background.
2. Convert the page into "Black/white" or Grayscale or Magic Color (feature of Camscanner)
3. Auto detect the page borders and gives me the handles to readjust the autodetected borders (like camscanner does)

I want this software to run on Windows PC.

PS: I already have Foxit PhantomPDF, Adobe Acrobat but none of them serve these purpose.